# How can I rename numbered files

Tags: bash, file-rename

I have 70ish shell scripts, named 1.man-pages.sh, 2.tcl.sh, 3.expect.sh etc.

I have made a mistake and need to rename these files by adding 1 to the number (eg 1.man-pages.sh => 2.man-pages.sh, 3.tcl.sh 4.expect.sh).

It's rather tedious to mv these each by hand.  Does anyone have a suggestion for a bash one liner?

Answer (score 3):

Not a onle-liner but close...

```
IFS=$'\n'
for f in $(printf '%s\n' [0-9]* | sort -rnt '.' -k1); do
    mv "$f" "$(( ${f%%.*}+1 )).${f#*.}"
done
```

Comment: Nice solution to reverse sort to make sure that `1.man-pages.sh` does not overwrite `2.man-pages.sh`

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *.sh; do
  number=$(cut -d '.' -f1 <<< $file)
  name=$(cut -d '.' -f2 <<< $file)
  extensiton=$(cut -d '.' -f3 <<< $file)
  re='^[0-9]+$' 
  if [[ $number =~ $re ]]; then
    mv $file "$(($number + 1)).$name.$extensiton"
  fi
done
```